# Intent passing in webpage instead of webview in android

Tags: android

I am hitting this URL "https//example.com" in the web browser. After hitting that URL in webpage I need to come to my app.

```
 val urll = "https://www.example.com"
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    i.data = Uri.parse(urll)
    startActivity(i)
```

after passing the URL  in webpage, I need to come into my app without clicking the back button

Answer (score 0):

In order to open your app from , you need to implement deep link.

First changes to your AndroiManfiest.xml  file, add below lines of code in your activity tag

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:scheme="https" />

</intent-filter>
```

after adding above lines of code you see your app pops up after loading url.

Comment: after hiting this url how can i navigate into my app

Comment: your app will appears automatically as soon as you load url mentioned in ANdroidManifest.xml

Comment: after add this line of code in manifest its not loading the url give brief description